# FFMPEG: boost video volume but preserve subtitles

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitles

Using as input video files that contain subtitle streams, currently I use this command to boost volume while copying video:

```
ffmpeg -i input_file    -vcodec copy -af "volume=10.0dB"  output_file
```

However in the output file the subtitles are lost.

What option should I use to preserve a specific subtitle stream, such as "Stream #0:14" for example?

Comment: Can't you just add a dialnorm value? https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#Other-Metadata-Options

Comment: The issue of boosting volume is already solved withe the command I'm using. I'm boosting all the audio, whereas the option you are referring to seems to affect just the dialogue (if they actually mean the entire audio then the documentation is not well written). What I'm asking is "how to preserve the subtitles", that currently are lost when I ran that command above.